# Quick Helper Annotaion in Java Editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to develop a eclipse plugin, which displays a Quick help annotation in the Java Editor.
The Quick Help icon should appear at every place, a type statement is missing in the Java-Code.

I'm a total noob in Eclipse plugin development. I read a few things about it and understand the idea with Extension points but I don't get how to add a annotation in the Eclipse Java editor.

Are there any examples or tutorials available for this problem/topic?
I don't know how to start and appreciate any help or hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it by placing a Marker and specifying a markerResolution for him.

#### Resources:

[Howto add a Marker](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html)
,
[Marker Customization](http://cubussapiens.hu/2011/05/custom-markers-and-annotations-the-bright-side-of-eclipse/) ,
[Adding a Quick Fix to a marker type](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_contributing_a_quickfix.htm)